# Read text files with multiple lists with spacings and commas exist between elements in the lists into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, read-write

I have a text file called `tropical.txt` that have multiple lists and each list is separated by a new line. Notice the comma is surrounded by spaces.

```
 space here and space here
         | |
['papaya' , 'mangosteen' , 'banana']
[]
['coconut' , 'mango']
['mangosteen' , 'papaya']
```

I tried the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tropical.txt', sep='\n', header=None, engine = 'python')
df
```

which gives me

```
ValueError: Specified \n as separator or delimiter. This forces the python engine which does not accept a line terminator. Hence it is not allowed to use the line terminator as separator.
```

If I were to just do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tropical.txt', header= None, engine = 'python')
df
```

The output isn't what I wanted

```
         0           1             2
0   ['papaya'   'mangosteen'    'banana']
1   []               None        None
2   ['coconut'      'mango']     None
3   ['mangosteen'   'papaya']    None
```

I am expecting

```
                        0   
0   [papaya,mangosteen,banana]
1   []  
2   [coconut,mango] 
3   [mangosteen,papaya]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the values in your expected output supposed to be lists or strings?

Comment: Supposed to be list

Comment: The spaces you see around the commas in the original lists may just be artifacts of how Pandas/Python is rendering your data to the console.  I'm not sure that anything need be done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read_csv`, by specifying a separator which will not occur in the lines (e.g. `\0`) (so that each line will be read as a whole) and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as a converter for the values:

```py
import ast

pd.read_csv('tropical.txt', header=None, sep='\0', names=['fruits'], converters={ 'fruits' : ast.literal_eval })
```

Output:

```
                         fruits
0  [papaya, mangosteen, banana]
1                            []
2              [coconut, mango]
3          [mangosteen, papaya]
```